# How I can declare a pointer to different classes that share common interfaces?

Tags: c++, class, interface

I'm using some 3rd party library classes that are defined like this.

```
class A : public Interface1, public Interface2 {};
class B : public Interface1, public Interface2 {};
```

They do not share just one common base class.  Is it possible to declare a single pointer type that can reference both class A and B types?

Please note that I'm using a 3rd party library and can't redefine A and B.  If I could then I would do this:

```
class Base : public Interface1, public Interface2 {};
class A : public Base {};
class B : public Base {};
```

and then I could simply use a pointer to the Base class.

```
Base *pBase;
```

Comment: The common base class is *either* `Interface1` *or* `Interface2`. There's really no way of going around it if you can't refactor the code. Which one you should use depends on the situation and what you currently need.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use it, but a `void*` can reference just anything. It is also possible to create a "pointer" class which can hold both depending on their type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly if you can't refactor the code.

That said, you can still make a class that erase the type and can be used whenever a pointer to `Interface1` or `Interface2` is required.
As an example:

```
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    S(T *t): iface1{t}, iface2{t} {}

    operator Interface1 *() { return iface1; }
    operator Interface2 *() { return iface2; }

private:
    Interface1 *iface1;
    Interface2 *iface2;
};
```

It has a major drawback with which I don't know if you can deal: a pointer to `S` cannot be assigned to a pointer to `InterfaceN`.
In other terms:

```
struct Interface1 {};
struct Interface2 {};

class A : public Interface1, public Interface2 {};
class B : public Interface1, public Interface2 {};

struct S {
    template<typename T>
    S(T *t): iface1{t}, iface2{t} {}

    operator Interface1 *() { return iface1; }
    operator Interface2 *() { return iface2; }

private:
    Interface1 *iface1;
    Interface2 *iface2;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    S sa{&a};

    // S can be assigned to a pointer to InterfaceN
    Interface1 *i1ptr = sa;
    Interface2 *i2ptr = sa;

    S *sptr = &sa;

    // sptr cannot be assigned to a pointer
    // to InterfaceN but you can get one
    // out of it dereferencing
    i1ptr = *sptr;
    i2ptr = *sptr;
}
```

If you can accept it, this is a dirty and feasible workaround.

---

To be honest, I cannot see why you should do that. You could simply create function templates and pass around pointers to `A`, `B` and all the other types.
Anyway, I don't know what's the real problem and I cannot figure out from the question.
Because of that, I hope it helps.